# Postgres localhost issue on Heroku Django application

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I cannot for the life of me figured this out. Whenever I try and run a database migration (currently using South for Django 1.6.5), I get this error:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've tried every settings config that I can think of. I have a base, local, and production settings file. In my production settings file I've even copied the database dictionary values from it's info page on heroku's website to ensure that they match. ex)

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'd3...k',
    'USER': 'yvg...f',
    'PASSWORD': '...',
    'HOST': '....amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

I don't see ANYWHERE that I'm telling it to look for localhost.

Comment: Tell how you configured `DATABASES['???'] =  dj_database_url.config()` ?

Comment: I had DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config() but it wasn't working, so I included the exact values as I posed above.

Comment: wat error you getting wen `default` ..?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your application to make sure `DATABASE_URL` is set? It should point to the database you're trying to use (`HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL` of sorts). Then, use the `dj_database_url.config()` as @rajasimon mentioned. See here as well https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database